# Unable to get any response in ajax

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

This is the ajax function that I am using. But still no response I am getting. 
I have given an alert in success `alert('hi')` but it is not working. But in error, it is saying that alert undefined.

```
function BindUsers() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // Method type
        url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=abc-news-au&sortBy=top&apiKey=1f9da58adc9f4197bc26b657821e0722',
        data: {},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('hi');
            if (data.d.length > 0) {

            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: are there any errors on `console '? and why do you use `type:"POST"`. if you are sending data via the query string in the URL you can use ``GET` and remove the `data:{}` part

Comment: What about: `$.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=abc-news-au&sortBy=top&apiKey=1f9da58adc9f4197bc26b657821e0722', function(data){
  console.log(data)
})`?!

Comment: Error is undefined .And what to put in type instead of POST?

Comment: No response for for getJSON.

Comment: i just added an answer please look into it

Comment: @Swadesh It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/w8whmc3m/

Comment: Not sure why you are using POST when what you want is GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the `contentType` that you are using

```
 contentType: 'application/json',
```

inside your ajax call, so that you do not receive the following error on your console

> Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

here is your ajax call how it will look like

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', // Method type
    url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=abc-news-au&sortBy=top&apiKey=1f9da58adc9f4197bc26b657821e0722',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('hi');
        if (data.d.length > 0) {

        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
    }
});
```

The URL that you are hitting is returning the following response and there is nothing like in it so obviously, it will throw an error on the line `if (data.d.length > 0) {` to `if (data.articles.length > 0) {`

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "source": "abc-news-au",
    "sortBy": "top",
    "articles": [{
            "author": null,
            "title": "'Butcher of Bosnia' Ratoko Mladic found guilty of genocide",
            "description": "A UN court sentences Bosnian Serb military commander Ratoko Mladic to life in prison for war crimes including genocide and crimes against humanity.",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-22/ratoko-mladic-found-guilty-of-genocide/9181354",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/9168162-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T11:14:23Z"
        },
        {
            "author": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/stephen-dziedzic/166934",
            "title": "The foreign policy White Paper explained",
            "description": "The Federal Government is releasing its foreign policy White Paper today. We break down what's in the document designed to shape Australia's approach to the world for years to come.",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-23/foreign-policy-white-paper-what-does-it-mean-for-australia/9182188",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/9182198-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T14:22:10Z"
        },
        {
            "author": null,
            "title": "Victoria set to make history as voluntary assisted dying bill passes Upper House",
            "description": "Historic voluntary euthanasia laws pass Victoria's Upper House after another marathon sitting.",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-22/euthanasia-victorian-parliament-passes-assisted-dying-laws/9156016",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/9156388-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T05:35:23Z"
        },
        {
            "author": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/rural/lucy-barbour/4592772, http://www.abc.net.au/news/4787636",
            "title": "'It's a fine line': Rinehart's sway over agriculture policy questioned after $40,000 Joyce award",
            "description": "Labor's agriculture spokesman raises concern over the undue influence Gina Rinehart has over Barnaby Joyce.",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-22/gina-rinehart-influence-over-barnaby-joyce-ag-policy-questioned/9181448",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/9178976-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T08:58:18Z"
        },
        {
            "author": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/irena-ceranic/4982426",
            "title": "Olivia Mead's battle for a slice of a 'colossal' mining fortune",
            "description": "As the secret daughter of one of Australia's richest men, few people knew of Olivia Mead's existence.",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-22/olivia-mead-the-secret-daughter-in-michael-wrights-will/8655548",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/9179590-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T06:33:33Z"
        },
        {
            "author": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/avani-dias/7304352",
            "title": "Australians of the Year unite in support of medical aid in Manus centre",
            "description": "Twelve former Australians of the Year have written an open letter pleading with the Prime Minister to allow doctors inside the recently closed Manus Island detention centre.",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-23/australians-of-the-year-open-letter-to-pm-on-manus-island/9181874",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/9182026-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T13:18:02Z"
        },
        {
            "author": null,
            "title": "Kerr's strike helps secure Matildas' 3-0 win over China",
            "description": "The Matildas win their sixth straight match, with Sam Kerr scoring a double in a 3-0 defeat of China.",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-23/sam-kerr-propels-matildas-to-victory-against-china/9181964",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/9182168-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T13:21:33Z"
        },
        {
            "author": null,
            "title": "Parents blame Government for 'toxic river' making kids sick",
            "description": "Outback parents were forced to drive their children hundreds of kilometres to bathe after a “man-made drought” exposed them to toxic river water.",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-22/parents-blame-government-for-toxic-river-making-kids-sick/9181886",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/9181842-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T12:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "author": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/dan-colasimone/6476504",
            "title": "How it all unravelled for Ange Postecoglou",
            "description": "Ange Postecoglou actually did it — he quit the Socceroos gig on the eve of the World Cup. What would motivate a man to exit stage left right before the big show?",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-22/how-it-all-unravelled-for-ange-postecoglou/9179040",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/8617900-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T02:20:59Z"
        },
        {
            "author": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/michael-collett/166910, http://www.abc.net.au/news/james-maasdorp/167000",
            "title": "Bring back Aussie Guus: Your verdict on who should be the next Socceroos coach",
            "description": "Ange Postecoglou won't be taking Australia to Russia 2018. Here's who you suggested should replace him as Socceroos coach.",
            "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-22/who-should-replace-ange-postecoglou-as-socceroos-coach/9180512",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/9016252-1x1-700x700.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2017-11-22T09:18:22Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That conflicts with `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: aaah sorry i couldnt get what you are saying

Comment: yeah correct you are @charlietfl i should have removed the other one.

Comment: Its working but data.d.length is 0.Because when I am giving the alert inside if (data.d.length > 0) is is showing nothing.

Comment: yes @Swadesh because there is nothing with the name `d` whose length you are trying to find see the answer I added the response that is received from the URL that you are sending the `ajax` request.

Comment: But you don't need to set that contentType...it is the `$.ajax` default. Also there is no request content in a GET anyway

Comment: i just updated the answer thanks for the correction @charlietfl

Comment: Then what to do to get the data for this json.

Comment: you are getting the data for the `JSON` if you want to count how many results were received against that `ajax` call then you should try `data.articles.length` rather than `data.d.length`.

Comment: Still I am not getting the response data.articles.length.

Comment: how could that be, what do you mean **not getting response `data.articles.length`** that would be because you are not doing anything inside the check `if (data.d.length > 0) {`, you should know what you are doing. this problem i recon is solved for now

Comment: When I am giving alert(data.articles.title) ,it is giving undefined.

Comment: to iterate the articles you need to do like below 
`if (data.articles.length > 0) {
                        var articles = data.articles;
                        for (var key in articles) {
                            alert(articles[key]['title']);
                        }
                    }`